# How to use Automorphisms[] on a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

I am having difficulty mixing the new post-Combinatorica graph data structure, with functionality apparently only in Combinatorica.

I have constructed a graph using `Graph[]`, e.g.,

```
n = 4; g = Graph[Range[n], {}] (* isolated vertices *)
```

The documentation on `Automorphisms[]` says:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

But then I cannot apply it to g:

```
grp = Automorphisms[g]
```

And in fact after the `Needs[]` statement, the meaning of `Graph[]` changes (it turns red).

Is there some standard way to handle this situation? I am currently focussed on just that one function `Automorphisms[]`, but clearly the issue can arise for many Combinatorica functions. (In fact, what I really want is the order of the automorphism
group of a graph.)

Thanks for your guidance!

---

**Addendum**.
I ended up following Szabolcs recommendation,
and connected to the `IGraph` library in `R` from Mathematica via `RLink` to count the automorphisms.
One application of this may be found at [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/147331/6094).
The set up and installation necessary is nontrivial.
I thank Szabolcs for his guidance throughout, as I could never had gotten it all
to work without his help.

Comment: Let me know if that other question doesn't help.  Out of the three solutions presented there, I currently prefer the RLink based one for its performance, but it does need some initial setup.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Oy, is it really that complicated?

Comment: I don't think it's complicated.  You just need to convert the built-in Graph type to a COmbinatorica graph using ``GraphUtilities`ToCombinatoricaGraph`` and then you can apply the Combinatorica functions.  The complicated part for me is keeping Combinatorica out of the context path.  That nasty ToCombinatoricaGraph keeps re-adding it.

Comment: If you only need the order of the group, and especially if performance is important, take a look at the RLink based answer (the last one).  That one shows how to get the order.  The setup there is really a bit complicated, but only the first time you do it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks. I shouldn't have reacted that way when you were trying to help me! :-) For my application, the RLink route is the best, even if it requires installation. Thanks.